# JavaScript let and var usage

Tags: javascript, function, variables, for-loop

A while ago, I read some article about using let and var in JavaScript and they're saying that a variable you declare using "var" keyword (even in for loop) works only within it's function, so why is it possible to make multiple for loops in one function, each of them look like : `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++);`
and JavaScript has no problem with "redeclaring" the i variable? Thanks :)

Comment: JavaScript allows variables declared with `var` to be redeclared.

Comment: You may also want to read up on variable scope.

Comment: @4castle That's not true. You're think of reassignment right now. You can change the value of a variable assigned using `let`, but cannot redeclare

Comment: @4castle So that means if there are more for loops, the i just gets back to zero and and continue with a new value? I just thought variables declared in start of for loop are valid just in the loop.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you're right. Edited. @Pollux `var` has a special behavior called "hoisting" where the variable declaration gets moved to the top of a function if it occurs anywhere inside a function.

Comment: @4castle ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS has a special case for `var` as it allows **hoisting**, which means multiple declaration of the same variables is allowed and they got moved to the enclosing functional scope. However they are still the same variable. Consider the following code:

```
function foo(){
 for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  console.log("x");
 }
 for(var i;i<6;i++){
  console.log("y");
 }
}

foo()
```

Notice there is no initialization of i in the second loop, but it will execute fine and produce 3 `x` and 3 `y`. It used to be a problem with old browsers, but new browser simply allows it with no error given.

Answer (score 1):

A seemingly small question with a complex answer. `var` is the old method declaration. You can declare it anywhere and as many times as you want. JavaScript will not care. All declared variables are available immediately, because declaration gets moved up to the very beginning of the function's code. This is known as hoisting.

`let` is the new way of declaring variables. `const` exists, but we're not interested in that right now. `let` is block scoped. The rules behind `let` and scoping can be confusing, but it's advantageous to learn/understand. It is the future of JavaScript. I thoroughly talk about it in my blog post, [here](https://andrewyueh.blogspot.com/2017/09/contrasting-let-const-and-var.html).

Answer (score 1):

let gives you the privilege to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement of expression unlike var.

var is rather a keyword which defines a variable globally regardless of block scope.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 introduced the 'let' keyword to tackle this issue only. It allows a variable to be bound to its scope within a function so that you cannot re-declare it outside preventing hoisting issues. Example -

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
console.log(i);
```

Here the output will be - 0 1 2 3 4 **5**
Instead of 5 we must get 'Uncaught Reference Error' since variable i should be accessible only within the function. Because of Hoisting in JavaScript, all the variables and function names are stored to one place before execution. So the code actually looks like the following -

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
}
console.log(i);
```

This is resolved if you use the **let** keyword.